# How to provision another vagrant machine?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have followed the 'getting start' section of vagrant documentation and successfully brought up a virtual box machine using the `hashicorp/precise32` box image

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
vagrant up
```

Now I want to create a new 64 bit ubuntu box. I have successfully added a new box

```
$ vagrant box list
chef/ubuntu-13.10   (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
hashicorp/precise32 (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
```

However `vagrant up` will only bring up the existing hashicorp/precise32 box.

Which section of documentation is related to creating second machine? Do I need to separate VagrantFile for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the existing Vagrantfile, and add another box.

As an example:

```
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  # config.vm.box = "base"

  config.vm.define :centos6 do |node1|
    node1.vm.hostname = 'centos.internal'
    node1.vm.box      = 'centos-65-x64-virtualbox-nocm.box'
    node1.vm.box_url  = 'http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/centos-65-x64-virtualbox-nocm.box'
    node1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.200.0.10"
  end

  config.vm.define :precise do |node2|
    node2.vm.hostname = "precise"
    node2.vm.box      = 'ubuntu-server-12042-x64-vbox4210-nocm.box'
    node2.vm.box_url  = 'http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/ubuntu-server-12042-x64-vbox4210-nocm.box'
    node2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.200.0.11"
  end
```

This is a section taken from a Vagrantfile created using `vagrant init`

The automatically created box "base" has been commented out, and two new boxes have been added. In order to bring these boxes up, you can use `vagrant up [boxname]`, for example `vagrant up centos6`

if you omit the argument, and just run `vagrant up`, all boxes list will be brought up, in the order they are defined in the Vagrantfile.

You can check the current status of the boxes in the Vagrantile by using `vagrant status`:

```
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

centos6                   not created (vmware_fusion)
precise                   not created (vmware_fusion)

This environment represents multiple VMs. The VMs are all listed
above with their current state. For more information about a specific
VM, run `vagrant status NAME`.
```